# Ordinal numbers in dart/flutter internationalization

Tags: flutter, dart, internationalization

Let's say I have a string like "Let's meet on the $n floor" and I want it internationalized. In English it should say "1st floor", "2nd floor", "3rd floor", "4th floor" and so on. In German it would be "1. Stock", "2. Stock", "3. Stock" and so on. How can I achieve this using the [intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) as `Intl.plural` only supports [zero, one, two, few and many](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/Intl/plural.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I made a package for this using the native platform libraries.

https://pub.dev/packages/ordinal_formatter

```
final ordinalString = await OrdinalFormatter().format(2) ?? ''; 
// -> 2nd

final localisedOrdinalString = await OrdinalFormatter().format(2, 'en_US') ?? ''; 
// -> 2nd
```